# Has any one developed M-Bus protocol on STM controller?

Tags: microcontrollers, protocols, stm32, wired, building-code

M-Bus is a building management side protocol which helps to communicate with the controller to get the available parameter values like current, voltage, power etc.
I have to develop an architecture which helps to get the data from Meters using the available protocol as M-Bus, I've STM32F030 controller and a datasheet of M-Bus, after searching a lot I couldn't find any working library, so is there anyone who has worked in this field please help.

Comment: There is a slim chance that you might get an answer on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You could try [mbus/libmbus](https://github.com/mbus/libmbus) that uses bitbanging so it only needs 4 GPIO. You could use it on almost any microcontroller.

It was not updated for 6 years but you could give it a go, even update it if needed.